# How to read this statement - listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]

Tags: java, android

I know how we inherit methods to methods to get the required output say for example - `editText.getText().toString()`; in order to get the text from the edit text entered. But I am slightly getting confused at the end of the statement where I pass the preference index along with the `getEntries()` method.

**1)** How is the prefIndex value acting with the get entries method to get the correct entry from the list preference?

**2)** How do we read such java statement?

Comment: Move `getEntries()` to it's own variable... Then do you understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have `listPreference.getEntries()` and you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html#getEntries()) that this returns the list of entries to be shown in the list in subsequent dialogs as an array.

Second you are accessing an specific element in this array using your `prefIndex` variable. It would be the same if you had done this:

```
CharSequence[] listPreferenceArray = listPreference.getEntries();
listPreferenceArray [prefIndex].doSomething();
```

I would recommend you to read about manipulating Java Arrays in [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) so you can understand how this works behind the scenes.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understood the concept as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you break it into its parts it would read:

- From the control on screen called listPreference
- get all of the entries as a collection
- from that collection get me the item at index prefIndex.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got to know how to read the statement step by step and understood as well. :)